# How to correctly set CURRENCY value in C++

Tags: c++, vb6, type-conversion, currency

In a C++ DLL which is used from a legacy VB6 program, I use the [CURRENCY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221223%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) data type to return some large values.

The code I'm using to fill it is this:

```
CURRENCY INT64toCURRENCY(INT64 int64) 
{
    CURRENCY ret;
    ret.int64 = int64 * 10000;
    return ret;
}
```

An integer overflow might arise here, but this is the least problem: The code doesn't work for negative numbers, `INT64toCURRENCY(-1)` appears in VB6 as 4 294 967 295 which is 2<sup>32</sup>–1.

However, `cout << INT64toCURRENCY(-1).int64` shows –10000 which I suppose is correct.

The VB6 program is basically this:

```
Public Declare Function My_Fun Lib "My_Lib.dll" _
(ByVal param As Boolean) As Currency
Dim c As Currency
c = My_Fun(True)
```

and `My_Fun` is defined as

```
extern "C" CURRENCY __stdcall My_Fun(VARIANT_BOOL param)
{
    return INT64toCURRENCY(-1);
}
```

What's the problem here and what is the correct code to convert a signed 64-bit integer to `CURRENCY`?

Comment: @JohnDibling: added "legacy" ;-)

Comment: Can you add your VB code that calls the C++ code?  It looks like the VB code is treating the high dword of the returned value as a signed 32-bit quantity.  Does CURRENCY work correctly in VB?  If you step thru this in the debugger (maybe in assembly language)  it ought to be clear enough what's happening, if not how to fix it.

Comment: @SteveTownsend: I added more code as you requested. I think that CURRENCY works correctly in VB6. I have yet to try debugging the assembly code although I doubt that it will mean much to me.

Comment: The Microsoft documentation on [developing DLLs for VB](http://vb.mvps.org/tips/vb5dll.asp) could be useful. This is actually the VB5 version, because the document was never updated for VB6, but the information is all accurate for VB6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VarCyFromI8 is the best solution.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644370(v=vs.85).aspx

The CURRENCY type is a bit tricky with regards to signed values; just use what is already there rather than mess with it on your own.

Note that the 64 bit variants are not technically supported until XP. Of course you could use the other VarCyFrom* functions, eg with a DECIMAL or an I4.

Comment: At minumum it will let you know whether anything is different between the two approaches.

Comment: Actually I am surprised this was not working as you listed. You could also try sending the -1 currency variant from vb to see if it is represented differently.

Comment: I did, it was received correctly! I think something is messing with my values during transmission ...